# exec("php -v”) vs phpinfo() -- different php version

Tags: apache, php

I have upgraded PHP version on my Mac to 7.3 with a command

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

and then

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

When I type `php -v` in terminal the new version shows up correctly.

---

I am using Apache shipped with macOS.

I have created a simple document in `localhost/phpinfo.php` that contains:

```
echo exec('which php');

echo '<br>';

$out = [];
exec("php -v" , $out);
foreach($out as $line) {
    echo $line, '<br>';
}

phpinfo();
```

The `phpinfo()` shows the new PHP 7.3.8 as expected, but the preceding lines, using `exec()` command produce a different result.

[image]

I was wondering if someone could explain why it is happening, does it matter at all, and if it is possible to fix it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "in a browser?" What web server/SAPI are you using?

Comment: The comment re using.bash_profile is wrong. However the correct answer depends on making it clearer how you run the app and how you want to run the app headless

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you've still got the older PHP binary installed (probably in `/usr/bin`).

When you change your `PATH` environment variable on the command to include `/usr/local/bin` - this means that the shell also searches that folder (and in that order) to find the program you want to run. In this case when you run php, it finds the new version in `/usr/local/bin` and runs that for you.

However that `PATH` environment variable change is local to that shell session only. It is not saved anywhere, and not used in other contexts.

Thus when you run the `phpinfo.php` script through the web server, it runs with a standard `PATH` that doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`. Thus the older PHP binary is run - showing the old version number.

It really doesn't matter at all - why would you want to run a PHP binary from a PHP script run by the webserver anyways?

In case you really wanted to do that and wanted it "fixed", you could do that by either changing your `exec()` call to include the full path:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/php -v" , $out);
```

or by changing the `PATH` environment variable for in your PHP script context.

Comment: I think that some web applications might make use of `exec()` and the results could be unpredictable/harder to debug if PHP versions are different, thus my question.  I see your point that it doesn’t really make sense to 'run a PHP binary from a PHP script’. Thanks for your comprehensive answer.

Comment: Hmm, that would be some odd web applications I would say... that's definitely not high on the "recommended list" for developers... in practice I don't think you'll have any problems.